# meaning of format reference in android attribute

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme, android-styles

Let's start with an example

```
<attr name="spinnerDropDownItemStyle" format="reference" />
```

How do I take this apart and understand it?

I watch the [Android themes & styles demystified - Google I/O 2016](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TIHXGwRTMWI) talk multiple times and I still don't understand how this reference thing works.

Answer (score 41):

`reference` format is used when the attribute refers to another resource ID. For example:

```
<!-- Declaration -->
<attr name="mydrawale" format="reference" />

<!-- Usage -->
app:mydrawable="@drawable/shape1"
```

So, resources like `@layout/...`, `@color/...`, `@style/...` are of type `reference`. However attribute formats like `color`, `boolean`, etc need also color literals (e.g. `0x00FF00`) and boolean literals (e.g. `true`) respectively.

In your case, `spinnerDropDownItemStyle` is an attribute that gets a resource like `@style/...` which by itself is a pointer to a resource entry of type style.

By the way, you can set the format to multiple types using `|`. For example for the following attribute both `@color/mycolor` and `0x00FF00` are acceptable.

```
<attr name="mycolor" format="reference|color" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It helps some. +1. Is it possible that you help me drill down into that example into the actual style they are using? I just want to see a complete example of my case and maybe the whole thing will finally click. Based on the talk there seems to have some sort of Object Oriented mischief going on as you drill deeper. I can see as much from your example but driving deeper into the referenced "style" for example would be helpful.

Comment: @NouvelTravay It's an attribute that gets a style id (e.g. `@style/mystyle`). This id can be later used to stylize the drop down items.

Comment: as far as i understand, color format can store references like reference format and also can store color values (#F44336). So if it is, what is the difference between "color" format and "reference|color" format ?